# Squashed and distorted view after device rotation

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiinterfaceorientation, cgrect

I've been reading through theses pages for a while now and have been having some trouble getting my `CGRect` to load properly. I learned it was because I'm forcing an orientation after `viewDidLoad` runs, and I'm trying to get the `CGRect` to draw again after. Basically, this is what I'm looking at:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(...);
    //...
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

When the view appears, the `CGRect` is very squashed and distorted, due to the rotation of the view.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the drawing code out from viewDidLoad and into its own function.  Then you can call the function from within the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and from the viewDidLoad.